# GDAL_translate and HEGtool

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, extents, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am using GDAL to convert a huge dataset of HDF into GEOTIFF. When I tried with the HEG tool the tiff file was according to my requirements, but when using GDAL I think the projection gets shifted when I input into ARCGIS. This the code that I am using:

```
for %A in ("C:\temp\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=epsg:4326" -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 -co "COMPRESS=PACKBITS" -sds "%A" "%A.tiff
```

[image: SHIFT IN PROJECTIONS I THINK]

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct projection?

Comment: Yes i have the correct Projections for both the file.